# ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack upon python list

Tags: python, list, plot

I currently have the following code:

```
sizes = [100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
rand_one_hundred = []
rand_one_thousand = []
rand_ten_thousand = []
rand_one_hundred_thousand = []
rand_one_million = []
random_values = [rand_one_hundred, rand_one_thousand, rand_ten_thousand, rand_one_hundred_thousand, rand_one_million]

for z in range(len(sizes)):
    for c in range(0, sizes[z]):
        random_values[z].append(random.random())

#Set labels and values
rand_labels, rand_values = zip(*Counter(random_values[3]).items())
#Arrange labels
rand_indexes = np.arange(len(rand_labels))
width = .5
#Subplot the figure and data
rand_fig, rand_ax1 = plt.subplots()
rand_ax1.bar(rand_indexes, rand_values, width)
#Format table to prevent overlapping
rand_fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

I am just trying to plot the results of the random number generator to compare against one I have made and I get this error:

```
rand_labels, rand_values = zip(*Counter(random_values[3]).items())
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

What is the error complaining about when I know the size of that list is equal to what it's supposed to be? Or am I doing something wrong when plotting this?

Comment: And `sizes` contains?

Comment: Sorry about that, please see the edit.

Comment: Could you explain that?

Comment: Explain what, how my attempts succeeded?

Comment: What you exactly mean by 'Cannot duplicate'. What exactly am I duplicating and why isn't it working?

Comment: I cannot duplicate the problem described in the question.

Comment: It was actually a indentation issue that I just fixed. My problem is now that the graph that is returned from that shows nothing but black. Are these the same results for you?

Comment: I didn't run the code that far. But I wouldn't be surprised; that is a *lot* of random data.

Comment: Is there anyway I can show that in a histogram or bar graph? I have it working for random data I have created using my own random number generator but it does not work for random data generated by python.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my later issue of not being able to graph the random numbers generated by the python random number generator by rounding the random values to 2 decimal places and plotting them on a graph.